# Adding sudo permissions to sudoers for user via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sudoers

I'm trying to create a post install script for Linux and I want to have the script edit the sudoers file so that users wont need to do `sudo visudo` and edit it manually.

In the script I have:

```
if [[ ! `sudo -l -U "$user" 2>&1 | grep "ALL"` ]]; then
    su -c "echo '$user ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers"
    su -c "echo '$user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers"
fi
```

the problem with this is that when I  `sudo whoami` after I run the script I get this output:

> sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 31 <<<
>   sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 31
>   sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
>   sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

How do I do this without ruining my sudoers file?

**EDIT:**
As requested here is my sudoers file:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Mind that it is not possible to do `cat /etc/sudoers` after the script has run.

**EDIT 2:**
The solution is to define $user as `user=$(whoami)`

Comment: It might help to show us what your sudoers file looks like.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Hi and thank you for your reply. I've edited the post and you can view my sudoers file now. Thank you.

Comment: Close voters: While this is not good practice, the question of how to programmatically manipulate `sudoers` is very real, and definitely on-topic here IMHO.

Comment: Perhaps you could have your script do the "cat sudoers" itself after modifying it, then. What you're showing here looks normal to me.

Comment: I think I've found a solution to my problem. If I'm right I need to store the username in a variable 'user=$(whoami)' and then user $user to look up if he's in sudoers file. Am I right?

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer (by selecting the green checkmark), not to edit the word "SOLVED" into the title. If the existing answer doesn't solve your problem, or is not the best solution, feel free to post and accept an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to have the script ask the user to enter his password and store the value in a variable to be used along with **Expect**. The script installs Expect if it's not installed and then the script does:

```
read -p "Please enter your password: " PASSWD
export PASSWD
username=$USER
export username

if [[ ! `sudo -l -U "$USER" 2>&1 | grep "ALL"` ]]; then
  expect -c '
      spawn "su -c \"cat <<EOF >> /etc/sudoers.d/$env(username)
          $env(username) ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
          $env(username) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
EOF
\"
      "
      expect "Password:\r"
      send $env(PASSWD)
      interact
  '
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

As the comment at the end of the default `sudoers` file suggests, you should create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Doing this from a (Debian) package's `postinst` seems fishy, though. Where does the value of `user` come from?

Also, any particular reason this user is not simply added to one of the existing groups, `admin` or `sudoers`?

Comment: hey there. I want to be able to install stuff without having to type in the password after sudo apt-get ...

Comment: I can see what you are doing, and I can guess what you are trying to a complish, but without details it is not clear whether you are being clever, or just doing it wrong. If that is your sole goal, why do you need a package for this? And again, how and where is `user` defined?

Comment: $user is defined as 'user=$(whoami)' and that is what was missing. Thank you.

Comment: But inside a `postinst` that will always be `root`, who does not need `sudo` privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file **/etc/sudoers** through "**pkexec visudo**", after when you will delete bad line, sudo will be work.